# Is there a way to modify the useState of another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I would like to write a function that can be called to change a useState hook, but the state is in a different function.

```
function Viewer(props) {
    const [linesToDisplay, setLinesToDisplay] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {

        if (props.json != undefined) {
            setLinesToDisplay(//set lines based on the json file)

        }
    }, []
    )

    function hideIDs(idsToHide) {
        var idsToShow = []
        linesToDisplay.forEach(line => {
            idsToHide.includes(line.id) ? null : idsToShow.push(line)
        })
        setLinesToDisplay(idsToShow)
    }
```

Obviously, I can't do this as I've implemented it. But I would like to know if there is some way to do this. If it's not possible, is there better way to implement state setting behaviour?

Comment: Do they need to be functional components or would classes be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously, I can't do this as I've implemented it.

Why not?  Perhaps I'm missing something here, but your code looks mostly correct except for the `forEach` callback and a missing dependency of `props.json`.

```
function Viewer(props) {
    const [linesToDisplay, setLinesToDisplay] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.json != undefined) {
            const lines = [] //some variable based on the json file
            setLinesToDisplay(lines);
        }
        // you need to include props.json as a dependency
    }, [props.json]
    )

    function hideIDs(idsToHide) {
        // can update state with a function of the previous state
        setLinesToDisplay(
            // filter the array to only ids which aren't in the array to hide
            // filter returns a new array and won't mutate state
            prevLines => prevLines.filter(
                line => !idsToHide.includes(line.id)
            )
        );
    }
...
```

Filtering the `linesToDisplay` array assumes that once lines are hidden they will not be shown again.  If lines get toggled on an off then you will want to store `idsToHide` in a separate state and derive the lines to show.  Something like this:

```
function Viewer(props) {
    // now stores all of the lines
    const [lines, setLines] = useState([])
    // the line ids to hide
    const [hiddenIds, setHiddenIds] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.json != undefined) {
            const lines = [] //some variable based on the json file
            setLines(lines);
        }
        // you need to include props.json as a dependency
    }, [props.json]
    )

    function hideIDs(idsToHide) {
        // add to existing array.  you could check for duplicates but it doesn't matter
        setHiddenIds( prevState => prevState.concat(...idsToHide));
    }

    // derive linesToDisplay from the two states
    const linesToDisplay = lines.filter(
        line => !hiddenIds.includes(line.id)
    )
...
```

Comment: Correct and really in depth. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you want to reuse the logic of handling the state to another component. that's a good use case of creating a custom hook.

```js
function useLines({ json }) {
   const [linesToDisplay, setLinesToDisplay] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (json != undefined) {
            setLinesToDisplay(//set lines based on the json file)
        }
    }, [])

    function hideIDs(idsToHide) {
        var idsToShow = []
        linesToDisplay.forEach(line => {
            idsToHide.includes(line.id) ? null : idsToShow.push(line)
        })
        setLinesToDisplay(idsToShow)
    }
    
    return [linesToDisplay, hideIds]
}
```

you can then use this hook to you component

```js
function Viewer(props) {
  const [lines, hideIds] = useLines(props)

  //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `setLinesToDisplay` as a props to another component. When the component calls it, it will change `linestodisplay`.